# get attribute value BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, urllib

I have a list of elements that I have extracted from a web-page:

```
property_list_items = soup.find_all("li", class_="hover propertyCard property-data-elem clickable")
    if len(property_list_items) > 0:
        for property_item in property_list_items:
            print property_item.meta['content']
            print soup(itemprop="geo")[0].get_text()
```

`property_item` element starts like this:

```
<li class="hover propertyCard property-data-elem clickable" data-city="Atlanta" data-feed-id="12310" data-list-index="0" data-location-id="52412" data-property-id="9000022319" data-property-state-code="GA" data-property-status="For Rent" id="propertyAnchor_0" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ApartmentComplex">
<div itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
  <meta content="33.82555" itemprop="latitude"/>
  <meta content="-84.33807" itemprop="longitude"/>
</div>
...
```

Now, when I iterate over all elements from alist, I want to extract specific information that is stored in an attribute - geographical coordinates.

I want to say smth like this:
`property_item['latitude']` and get the value `33.82555`

However, so far I have had no luck. `property_item.meta['content']` results in only the first "value" (33.82555), and `soup(itemprop="geo")[0].get_text()` return empty result.

I want to be able to parse a SPECIFIC element one at a time, preferably without using `find_all()` (if it is at all possible) because `latitude` and `longitude` only make sense in context of specific property, and I will also need to relate them to a property id, etc.

Sorry in advance for a newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select by attribute text using a css selector, i.e using the *itemprop* values from  the meta tags:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: h = """<li class="hover propertyCard property-data-elem clickable" data-city="Atlanta" data-feed-id="12310" data-list-index="0" data-location-id="52412" data-property-id="9000022319" data-property-state-code="GA" data-property-status="For Rent" id="propertyAnchor_0" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ApartmentComplex">
   ...: <div itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
   ...:   <meta content="33.82555" itemprop="latitude"/>
   ...:   <meta content="-84.33807" itemprop="longitude"/>
   ...: </div>
   ...: </li>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"lxml")

In [4]: lat, lon = soup.select_one("meta[itemprop=latitude]")["content"], soup.select_one("meta[itemprop=longitude]")["content"]

In [5]: print(lat,lon)

('33.82555', '-84.33807')
```

`meta[itemprop=latitude]`uses a [*css selector*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find the meta tag that has an *itemprop* with the text value *latitude* and you pull the content from that and the same logic for the *longitude*.

If you wanted to be more specific you could find the *li* with the *hover...* class and pull the meta tags from that.

```
li = soup.select_one("li.hover.propertyCard.property-data-elem.clickable")
lat, lon = li.select_one("meta[itemprop=latitude]")["content"], li.select_one("meta[itemprop=longitude]")["content"]
print(lat,lon)
```

Or use the *div* with the *itemprop* value of *geo*.

```
geo = soup.select_one("div[itemprop=geo]")
lat, lon = geo.select_one("meta[itemprop=latitude]")["content"], geo.select_one("meta[itemprop=longitude]")["content"]
print(lat,lon)
```